# Look for substring in string with item followed to searched sentence

Tags: c#, regex

what is a proper way in C# to find substring in string and retrieve it with word followed to searched sentence, for example in string:

```
 string str = "On the screen the faint, old, robed figure of Mercer toiled upward, and all at once a rock sailed past him.";
```

search for sub-string:

```
 string find = "figure of";
```

to get desired output:

```
 figure of Mercer
```

Comment: Also take a look at string.IndexOf, sometimes that's all you need (and IndexOfAny and LastIndexOf...)

Comment: What happens when you have `figure of --speech---` ?

Comment: @sln Hello, it is just example of getting following word of searching instance, which also can be different searching phrase

Comment: @Flydog57 Hello, string indexOf, indexOfAny and LastIndexOf, can you show any example for particular goal

Comment: I got it working, but it's way too complicated.  Go with a Regex; it's much simpler.  Whitespace handling is a pain trying to figure out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this pattern `([inputString] +(\\w+))`

use regex `group` and space to get word.

```
string search = "figure of";
string str = "On the screen the faint, old, robed figure of Mercer toiled upward, and all at once a rock sailed past him.";
string regex_Str = string.Format("({0} +([\\w+]+))", search);
var result = new Regex(regex_Str).Match(str);
Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9Qwr1)

Comment: Hello, what is difference  `({0} * ([a-zA-Z]+))` and `({0} +([\\w+]+))`?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+` same with ` [\\w+]+`, `*` mean match `0` or `1`,`+` mean match more than 1  more infomation you can see this link https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html